# How to mount google disk to docker run -v

Tags: google-compute-engine, docker-machine

Is it is possible to use docker-machine with a google disk?

I have a docker-machine running via the docker-machine driver. I then need to be able to: `docker run -v`"path to google disk" From the terminal / docker-machine?

Comment: Could you please clarify what your use case is and what you're trying to accomplish? Are you trying to create + mount a new persistent disk? Or use a directory on an already-attached and mounted persistent disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting use case.  There isn't a Volume Plugin to do that at the moment.  But I may look into it (I just experimented with writing a Volume Plugin for Google Cloud Storage).

However, you should be able to mount the disk on the Docker Machine itself, and then reference it as you would with any other filesystem directories.

E.g.,

1. [Attach a disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#attach_disk) to the instance
2. [Format and mount](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#formatting) (e.g. mount to `/mnt/mydisk`)
3. Run `docker run -ti -v /mnt/mydisk:/data busybox /bin/sh`

Answer (score 0):

First use file manager and un-Mount the drive, use sudo fdisk —l to find the /dev/ID in my case its /dev/sda2

```
sudo mkdir /mnt-LaCie-2TB
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt-LaCie-2TB
TO unmount use
sudo umount /mnt-LaCie-2TB #note u
```

Then in my case my image contains jupyter so

```
docker run -i -t —-rm -p 8888:8888 -v /mnt-LaCie-2TB:/opt/LaCie-2TB <imageID> bash
```

Then inside the container

```
# jupyter notebook —-ip 0.0.0.0 —-allow-root
```

Your external drive will be accessible in the opt directory.